# Determination of position of a vocalizing animal

Tags: pam, pamguard, soundscape, localization

I am interested in passive acoustic monitoring of bird in difficult to access terrain. But then I want to know if sensors can determine the exact position of vocalising birds

Comment: Welcome @Dickson Anobi Matthew. Could you please provide more detail to your question - this can help generate a targeted answer. Questions that seem potentially relevant to the current one include [1](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/63/does-the-type-of-bird-call-significantly-effect-localization) and [2](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-minimum-number-of-micro-hydro-phones-needed-to-perform-3d-tracking/83#83) .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what are the minimum number of micro/hydro-phones needed to perform 3d tracking?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-minimum-number-of-micro-hydro-phones-needed-to-perform-3d-tracking)

Comment: Is this a pamguard question? It has a pamguard tag. Should it?

Comment: This is really not a question. Please place an explicit question into your post

Comment: Hi @dickson! Your question is very vague, and there is a fair amount of research on this topic available. Please show that you have made an effort to answer this question yourself using traditional research techniques. This will also help narrow the focus of your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to determine the position of a vocalizing animal from pam. However, I am not aware that the censors will automatically determine the sound source.
You need to know the exact GPS position of each and every microphone. All your ARU (acoustic recording unit) should be temporally synchronized. With some devices it is possible to use GPS time-sync:

https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/products/song-meter-sm4-acoustic-recorder-with-time-synchronization

But it is very expensive materials.

I suggest first you read these articles on the topic to develop a better idea about how you would proceed to record and then estimate the position of the vocalizing individual:

**Acoustic localization of terrestrial wildlife: Current practices and future opportunities**:

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ece3.6216

**Acoustic monitoring in terrestrial environments using microphone arrays: applications, technological considerations and prospectus**:

https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2664.2011.01993.x

**Sound Finder: a new software approach for localizing animals recorded with a microphone array**:

https://doi.org/10.1080/09524622.2013.827588

Have a good day

Comment: This answers my question. I remain grateful.